# Missing return in a function expected to return 'UIFont?'

Tags: ios, swift2, uifont

I have a custom UITextfield in swift called COSTextField. It is something like

```
class COSTextField: UITextField {
    func customFont() -> UIFont? {
        if let font = self.font {
            return UIFont(name: kCOSFontRegular, size: font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to extend this COSTextField class and override the customFont method. My new class looks like

```
class COSTextFieldLight: COSTextField { 
    override func customFont() -> UIFont? {
        if let font = self.font {
            return UIFont(name: kCOSFontLight, size: font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error `Missing return in a function expected to return 'UIFont?'`. If I add a return nil statement at the end of my override function, I get an error `Non-void function should return a value`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you will need an `else` part of the optional binding  `if let font = self.font { ...`, because if that fails, you will not return anything.

Comment: I tried adding a `return nil` statement right after the `if let font = self.font { ...`. But that too gives me an error `Non-void function should return a value`

Comment: I meant `if let font = self.font {...} else { return nil }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return nil` *just after* the `if let` branch:

```
class COSTextField: UITextField {
    func customFont() -> UIFont? {
        if let font = self.font {
            return UIFont(name: kCOSFontRegular, size: font.pointSize)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class COSTextFieldLight: COSTextField {
    override func customFont() -> UIFont? {
        if let font = self.font {
            return UIFont(name: kCOSFontLight, size: font.pointSize)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

That way, if the `if let` condition fails, your function will return nil.

Comment: Yeah I figured that is it. But I am still trying to understand why it only complains about missing return in the override function and not in the original `func customFont() -> UIFont?` function

Comment: Your answer is correct of course.  Something odd though.  If you type the above functions into a Playground without the `return nil` statements, and then add them, it will show an error `Non-void function should return a value`.  Deleting them and adding the functions back as a whole makes it work.  Some problem with the incremental compile.

Comment: @EricD. for me it only complains on the override function when I remove the `return nil` line

Comment: I started seeing an error after I cleaned the project. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @EricD. I'm having an issue which may be related to font, I'm really stumped, if you could take a look if you have any ree time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285246/heightforrowatindexpath-crashing-intermittently